# How to find the first line in auto wrapping html

Tags: javascript, line-breaks

Assuming I have a `div` with a fixed width and some auto wrapping text inside. Now I want to insert a `span` element at the end of the first line. Because the text isn’t written in a specific structure, the first line could contain five words as well as three or just one. So I would need to find the position on which the automatic line-break happens. Is that possible or do I need to insert a manual `br` or some marker?

Comment: I think you would need a manual `<br />`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's painfully possible. The question is why are you trying to do this? There may be an easier way to accomplish what you need.

If you decide you still need to do this, what you would have to do is create a clone of this div that cannot be seen. You would set this cloned div's height to 1px or something like that. You can then fill this clone with identical text word by word. Once the div's scrollHeight jumps, you know that the first word wrap has occurred. You can then use this data to figure out where the original paragraph' first line has word wrapped.

Comment: Thanks, that will do the trick. Just thinking about an experimental layout. I will post the final javascript, if I will hold on to this layout.

Answer (score 0):

You need add  or some marker. Different browser calculate how many words should be placed in the first line. And if user change setting of browser, for instance increase font size, the first line will change number of words.